# Wildcard 301 redirect in .htaccess from urls without /en to urls with /en

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two languages installed on my Joomla site. One is english which url is in this format:

http://www.domain.com/en/about

Another language is arabic with this format:

http://www.domain.com/ar/about

How can i make a wildcard 301 redirect for urls without language code to english URLs?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only language codes are 2 characters and not your pages, and some page other than "/" is requested (note, not tested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/.+
RewriteRule (.*) /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

See [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) documentation. In regards to `RewriteCond TestString CondPattern`:

> You can prefix the pattern string [*CondPattern*] with a '!' character (exclamation mark) to specify a non-matching pattern.

Comment: Thanks Zamnuts, I just used php 301 redirection instead.